# Xcode: Program received signal: "SIGABRT"

Tags: iphone, sdk

I'm a newbie and when code in SDK 4.2, this notification always show, althought I just make a simple program

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's a crash.  Look at the stack trace via the debug navigator for more details.

Comment: Oh yeah, this is next screen when i click it [IMG]http://i569.photobucket.com/albums/ss133/Angchon/Error.jpg – user1041011[/IMG}

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you **don't** use 4.2 because `@autoreleasepool` in main.m is used since 5.0.

Secondly, SIGABRT means that you have an error in your code somewhere and your app crashed because of that. If you put your whole log here, I will be able to tell you where it is.

Comment: Oh yeah, this is next screen when i click it
http://i569.photobucket.com/albums/ss133/Angchon/Error.jpg